# How to get a distinct list from a List of objects?

Tags: c#, linq, class, list, properties

I have a `List<MyClass> someList`.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Prop1...
    public int Prop2...
    public int Prop3...
}
```

I would like to know how to get a new distinct `List<MyClass> distinctList` from `List<MyClass> someList`, but only comparing it to `Prop2`.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no really easy built-in support for this in the framework - but you can use the [`DistinctBy`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) implementation I have in [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/).

You'd use:

```
var distinctList = someList.DistinctBy(x => x.Prop2).ToList();
```

(You can take just the `DistinctBy` implementation. If you'd rather use a Microsoft implementation, I believe there's something similar in the System.Interactive assembly of [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896).)

Comment: @Jon, does it really worth to use MoreLINQ for such things instead of implementing `IEqualityComparer` for `IEnumerable.Distinct`?

Comment: @zerkms: Personally I would use MoreLINQ or Reactive Extensions, yes... it really doesn't take much effort to include it, and the calling code ends up being more readable IMO.

Comment: @Jon, I just worry about adding dependencies on 3rd party code. In other hand - built in solution obliges us to write bloated code... :-S

Comment: @Jon do you happen to know why they didn't add an overload to Distinct that takes a lambda? Same question for the overload of Contains.

Comment: DistinctBy is nice, but what if i want to implement more complex logic, like 2 fields?

Comment: @Ilya: That's easy: `foo.DistinctBy(x => new { x.Prop1, x.Prop2 });`

Comment: @Stilgar: I don't know... there are various additional features which would be *nice* to have in LINQ. Of course they'd then have to be implemented in LINQ to SQL etc as well...

Comment: @Jon, thanks. @zerkms: if you do not want to reference 3rd party code, write it yourself. it's pretty much easy to do.

Comment: OMG, this is so... so... Satisfying. Thanks!

Comment: @TejasviHegde: It would be helpful if in future you could just suggest the relevant edit to be approved...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I some how I couldn't look at edit option :)

Comment: epic, no need to actually  use morelinq, just implement their distinctby

Answer (score 162):

You can emulate the effect of `DistinctBy` using `GroupBy` and then just using the first entry in each group. Might be a bit slower that the other implementations though.

```
someList.GroupBy(elem=>elem.Prop2).Select(group=>group.First());
```

Comment: Also works with multiple properties: `someList.GroupBy(elem=> new { elem.Prop1, elem.Prop2, elem.Prop3 }).Select(group=>group.First());`

Comment: This should have been accepted answer. It does not depend on any external libraries and clean

Comment: @TejasviHegde: Well, it has downsides compared with using `DistinctBy` as well: 1) it takes more memory, as it builds a group for every element; 2) it can't stream the results - it has to completely read `someList` before it yields any elements. I would say the MoreLINQ approach is cleaner.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks! I didn't think from this angle :) Btw. I just went through the code of your library, I loved the coding style and neat implementation!

Comment: This really helped me a lot. we can also add .ToList() at the end. btw really helpful

Answer (score 27):

you need to use `.Distinct(..);` extension method.
Here's a quick sample:

```
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Point>
    {
        public bool Equals(Point x, Point y)
        {
            return x.X == y.X;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Point obj)
        {
            return (int)obj.X;
        }
    }
```

**Do not forget about `GetHashCode`**.

Usage:

```
List<Point> p = new List<Point>();
// add items
p.Distinct(new Comparer());
```

Comment: What should be happened if we call `p.Distinct();` without `new Comparer()` parameter? In general `ListOfObjects.Distinct()` how works?

Comment: @ImanMahmoudinasab, in general, .NET will use equality methods(Equals and GetHashCode) from the object. If they are not defined, they would be compared by reference, therefore, an object would be equal to itself only.

Comment: How can we use Distinict , without writing " new Comparer() " as @ImanMahmoudinasab said ?

Comment: @Parsa writing distinct without comparer is easy `p.Distinct();`. Distinct without comparer is usefull only when you want to check two _instance_ is same referane (same memory) not equal (diferent memory but equal property value).

Comment: @Parsa Example: `var a=new Person("Iman"); var b=new Person("Iman"); var pList=new List<Person>(); pList.Add(a); pList.Add(b); pList.Add(a);` in this example `pList` contains `a` twice and using `pList.Distinc()` will give you just **one** `a` and one `b`. Notice that both `a` and `b` has equal name: `Iman`. So `pList.Distinc().Count()` is **2**. but with a comparer `pList.Distinc(new NameComparer()).Count()` is **1**.

Comment: This is awesome! I love this solution

Answer (score 22):

Override **Equals(object obj)** and **GetHashCode()** methods:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((MyClass)obj).Prop2 == Prop2;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Prop2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and then just call:

```
List<MyClass> distinctList = someList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Since the introduction of value tuples, if you want a LINQ equivalent to SQL's DISTINCT

```
items.GroupBy(item => (item.prop1, item.prop2, ...)).Select(group => group.First())
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to `Distinct` your list by multiple fields, You have to create an instance of `IEqualityComparer` interface:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyModel>
{
    public bool Equals(MyModel x, MyModel y)
    {
       // compare multiple fields
        return
            x.Field1 == y.Field1 &&
            x.Field2 == y.Field2 &&
            x.Field3 == y.Field3 ;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyModel obj)
    {
        return 
            obj.Field1.GetHashCode() + 
            obj.Field2.GetHashCode() + 
            obj.Field3.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use the comparer to distinct your list:

```
var distinctedList = myList.Distinct(new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I needed the simplest answer and at this time (with .NET 4.5.1) I found the following to be the most straight-forward answer I could get to:

```
IEnumerable<long> allIds = waitingFiles.Values.Select(wf => wf.groupId).Distinct();
```

My situation is that I have a ConcurrentDictionary that looks something like:
`ConcurrentDictionary<long, FileModel>`

The ConcurrentDictionary Values property is basically my `List<FileModel>`.

*FileModel has a groupId that isn't necessarily unique (though, obviously the key (long) that I use to add the FileModel object into the dictionary is unique to the FileModel).

**Named for clarity in the example.*

The point is that I have a large number of FileModels (imagine 100) in the ConcurrentDictionary and within those 100 FileModels there are 5 different groupIds.

At this point I just need a list of the distinct groupId.

So, again if I just had a list of FileModel the code would look like the following:

```
IEnumerable <long> allIds = allFileModel.Select(fm => fm.groupId).Distinct();
```