# How to return distinct data to DropDownListFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, distinct, html.dropdownlistfor

I apply .Net MVC structure with C#. In the controller, I want to **distinct** specific column (IndustryName), and return the result to **Html.DropDownListFor** in view. But I get a running time error at view:

> System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.String' not include
>   'IndustryName' property.

Is there any one meet such problem, and how to solve it?
  Thank you very much for your helping.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var industrys = this._pmCustomerService.GetAll().Select (x => x.IndustryName).Distinct();
   ViewBag.Industrys = new SelectList(industrys, "IndustryName", "IndustryName", null);
   return View(); 
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IndustryName, (SelectList)ViewBag.Industrys)
```

Comment: Can we have some info on what the Industry's is? As in the class? Seems as though IndustryName is not a property on the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is returning `IEnumerable<string>` (you select only the `IndustryName` property in the `.Select()` clause. `string` does not contain an property named `IndustryName` so you get this error. Just change the `SelectList` to

```
ViewBag.Industrys = new SelectList(industrys);
```

This will bind the options value and display text to the value of `IndustryName`

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you create `SelectList` with wrong collection. This should work i think.

```
var industrys = this._pmCustomerService.GetAll().Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.IndustryName,
                    Text = x.IndustryName
                }).Distinct();
ViewBag.Industrys = new SelectList(industrys);
return View();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following sample implementation may help you fix the problem:

```
var industries= this._pmCustomerService.GetAll()
                    .GroupBy(ind => new { ind.IndustryName})
                    .Select(group => new SelectListItem 
                                     { 
                                       Text = group.First().Name, 
                                       Value = group .First().Name 
                                     }
                           );
ViewBag.Industries= industries;
```

You can find more about the 'GroupBy & Select' approach instead of using linq's Distinct(), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983618/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-collection-using-iequalitycomparer-linq-distinct)

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlIndustries",(@ViewBag.Industries) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

If you like to use DropDownListFor helper instead then modify view code as follows:

```
@{
    var industries = ViewBag.Industriesas IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> industries , industries )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only Selecting IndustryName which is obviously of type `String`, use `DistinctBy()` from [**MoreLinq by Jon Skeet**](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), here is the reference [**SO post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991728/how-to-get-a-distinct-list-from-a-list-of-objects):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var industrys = this._pmCustomerService.GetAll().DistinctBy(x => x.IndustryName); 
   ViewBag.Industrys = new SelectList(industrys, "IndustryName", "IndustryName", null);
   return View(); 
}
```