# How to get distinct value from array of object in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an `array` of an `object` called storing, some of the object's attribute (`skuID`) is the same with some of the other storing with different (`storingID`), how do i make my `array` `distinct` depending on their (`skuID`)?

```
Storing(string storingID, skuID, storageID, price, expiry)
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
List<storing> storingAll = (List<storing>)Session["storingAll"];
List<storing> displayedStoring = storingAll.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Comment: @Sahir And yet you proposed an answer using LINQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
storingAll.GroupBy(x=>x.skuID).Select(group=>group.First());
```

Note that this solution uses no external libraries. Simple group by the first occurrence of skuID.

Reference:
[How to get a distinct list from a List of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991728/how-to-get-a-distinct-list-from-a-list-of-objects)

Comment: It uses no additional libraries, but may well consume a lot more memory than using MoreLINQ, as it needs to build up the groups. It's also non-streaming: it has to read *all* the elements before it can emit *any* of them.

Comment: Agreed. You gotta make a trade off here.